# Slow MySQL selects with where PK > x

Tags: mysql

I have a table with about 5 million rows of the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `asin` char(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
...other fields...
  PRIMARY KEY (`asin`),
  KEY `lang` (`lang`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm trying to run a script on it all, for this I use "select * from books where asin > X limit 10000" and remember the last PK.

I expected this query to be very fast since I'm querying by PK, but the performance is slowly degrading with the query taking almost 1 minute now (used to be better in the beginning). Why does this happen?

Explain example:

```
mysql> explain select * from books where asin > 'B000OT86OY' limit 10000;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | books | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 10      | NULL | 4670633 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: How many rows is returned?

Comment: @ad4s 10000 each time

Comment: would anyone please explain why this could possibly be downvoted?

Comment: Try LIMIT 100, if still slow try changing PK to an INT type to perform better comparison using ">" operator. Provide more information about the query

Comment: there's some specific reason because you're using char as primary key?

Comment: @Abe, since amazon uses such primary keys and these items are taken from there

Comment: have you try a diferent approach to your model, such as, include a `id int` as primary key and your `asin` field as unique key? Your where clause, what it's the kind of data then you want to filter? It is numeric? char?

Comment: This query should be executed in less than a second. I'm pretty sure some important information is missing in the question. At least post the EXPLAIN result. And what do you mean by "remember the last PK"?

Comment: If the values of char(10) are not numbers, how to compare using mathematical operator and range index. Every row needs to be evaluated

Comment: As @PaulSpiegel said, your EXPLAIN result will be useful.

Comment: @Abe I've added an EXPLAIN example

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Added an explain example, also by remember last PK I mean that the script takes 10k rows ordered by PK, saves last one, then gets the next chunk using where PK > [value saved]

Comment: So you are executing the query 50 times, and every time you you are selecting 10000 rows and then throwing away 9999 of them? Try `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9999`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, "select 10k rows starting with id 0", "last row has id 11000 because of gaps", "do stuff for each row", "select 10k rows starting with id 11000", ..., repeat until select returns 0 rows

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mitigate the issue by performing `ALTER TABLE books ORDER BY asin ASC`. I imagine the issue was that the rows were physically far apart on my disc, so after doing the above, the query became instantaneous.